# Access rules for media library upload path

Tags: security, media-library

I have a multisite setup and I want to use a dedicated folder under media library for all the images that editors can upload to sitecore. And under that folder, I want to have subfolders per website, so the structure is like:

```
/media library
 /Customer
   /France
   /Belgium
   /Spain
```

So I have setup editor roles for the different sites (countries) and want them to be able to only upload to their corresponding media library folder. So, for example, an editor for the France website should only be able to upload to the media library/Customer/France path. I also set the source of the image fields to /media library/Customer and expected the editors to only see the subfolder of their site. But when a user tries to add an image, he can only add images directly to the folder /media library/Customer and none of the subfolders is visible/available. How is that possible? And is this the way to go to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you add read and write to each folder for the respective user role? For example, author in France should have read and write access to the folder France else he/she will not see the folder

Comment: And as per your requirements, you want to have like a dynamic source for the media field for each content author based on the role to show the specific directory. Example the source for content author for France will be media library/Customer/France. For this requirement, I'm pretty sure you will require a custom field which extends the media field and update the source based on the author role as I don't think there is an OOTB way with the access roles as the path is different for each user